# Python Dashboard Application With Multiple Upload Boxes To Update Graphs

Tags: python, callback, upload, plotly, dashboard

I'm making a dashboard application where you upload a CSV file and it graphs (using plotly) the contents of that file.

At the moment, I have the dashboard application running with one upload box and three different types of graphs (each with callbacks so that the graphs get updated when a file is uploaded).

This is the app's current layout.

```
# appropriate imports

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.H1(children=''),

        # uploader
        dcc.Upload(
            id='upload-data-1',
            children=html.Div([
                'Drag and Drop or ',
                html.A('Select Files'),
            ]),
            style={
                'width': '100%',
                'height': '60px',
                'lineHeight': '60px',
                'borderWidth': '1px',
                'borderStyle': 'dashed',
                'borderRadius': '5px',
                'textAlign': 'center',
                'margin': '10px'
            },
            # Allow multiple files to be uploaded
            multiple=True
        ),
        
        dcc.Graph(id = 'graph_1'), # choropleth map
        dcc.Graph(id = 'graph_2'), # scatter plot
        dcc.Graph(id = 'graph_3'), # graph
    ]
)

#callback 1
@app.callback(Output('graph_1', 'figure'),
    [
        Input('upload-data-1', 'contents'),
        Input('upload-data-1', 'filename')
    ]
)

# function which updates graph_1

# callback 2
@app.callback(Output('graph_2', 'figure'),
    [
        Input('upload-data-1', 'contents'),
        Input('upload-data-1', 'filename')
    ]
)

# function which updates graph_2

# callback 3
@app.callback(Output('graph_3', 'figure'),
    [
        Input('upload-data-1', 'contents'),
        Input('upload-data-1', 'filename')
    ]
)

# function which updates graph_3
```

This is fully functional right now. Notice that all three graphs are updated with a single upload.

But I want to change this layout. I've essentially decided graph_2 and graph_3 are unnecessary, and I would like to create two versions of graph_1, each with their own individual upload boxes so that the two  graphs can be viewed and compared. In theory, I want the final version to look something like this...

```
# appropriate imports

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.H1(children=''),

        # uploader
        dcc.Upload(
            id='upload-data-1',
            children=html.Div([
                'Drag and Drop or ',
                html.A('Select Files'),
            ]),
            style={
                'width': '100%',
                'height': '60px',
                'lineHeight': '60px',
                'borderWidth': '1px',
                'borderStyle': 'dashed',
                'borderRadius': '5px',
                'textAlign': 'center',
                'margin': '10px'
            },
            # Allow multiple files to be uploaded
            multiple=True
        ),
        
        dcc.Graph(id = 'graph_1_v_1'), # choropleth map 1
        
        dcc.Upload(
            id='upload-data-2',
            children=html.Div([
                'Drag and Drop or ',
                html.A('Select Files'),
            ]),
            style={
                'width': '100%',
                'height': '60px',
                'lineHeight': '60px',
                'borderWidth': '1px',
                'borderStyle': 'dashed',
                'borderRadius': '5px',
                'textAlign': 'center',
                #'margin': '10px'
            },
            # Allow multiple files to be uploaded
            multiple=True
        ),
        
        dcc.Graph(id = 'graph_1_v_2'), # choropleth map 2
    ]
)

#callback 1
@app.callback(Output('graph_1_v_1', 'figure'),
    [
        Input('upload-data-1', 'contents'),
        Input('upload-data-1', 'filename')
    ]
)

# function_1, which updates graph_1_v_1

# callback 2
@app.callback(Output('graph_1_v_2', 'figure'),
    [
        Input('upload-data-2', 'contents'),
        Input('upload-data-2', 'filename')
    ]
)

# Call function_1 again, only this time to update graph_1_v_2
```

This is where I'm having issues. The first upload box and graph work just fine when I test it, and I THINK the second upload box is working (there's no reason why it shouldn't be, since its essentially the same code as the first box), but graph_1_v_2 is never getting updated. I'm nearly positive it is because my callback is being done incorrectly. I've tried a couple different things, including various methods of combining both callbacks into one and having one callback use the output of the other as an input, but I'm still not having much luck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A quick update. I am able to successfully do what I want to do if, instead of calling function_1 for both callbacks, I create an entirely new function with the same contents as function_1 (let's call it function_1_copy). But function_1 is a long function and I don't want to have to repeat so much code.